# Simple Java Script not working in Safari?

Tags: javascript

This script is working fine in chrome and firefox but not safari...

Any help please?

```
<ul class="SubMenu">
    <li>Shop By Category
        <ul>
          <li>
            ----Some Text----
          </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").click(function () {
        //Toggle the child but don't include them in the hide selector using .not()
        $('li > ul').not($(this).children("ul").toggle()).hide();

    });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a working jsfiddle?

Comment: "not working" how? What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? What do you see in the console? When you debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For testing sake I added all this in an html file containing the following, and everything seems to be working fine across all browsers. How is it failing exactly?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="SubMenu">
      <li>Shop By Category
        <ul>
          <li>
            ----Some Text----
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("li").click(function () {
        //Toggle the child but don't include them in the hide selector using .not()
        $('li > ul').not($(this).children("ul").toggle()).hide();

        });
    });

 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I Just tryed your script and its working on safari, Il have to run though my code and check for errors i only uploaded the basic structure here maybe its my css.

Comment: I have an error in a script that was running before this one, Letting safari read this one first fixed my isssue on this problem. Thanks